# Mysql delete query using zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, sql-delete, zend-db

i'm developing an application where there is a function (correctly called) that receive an id an should delete records from a table where the id is present.

This is my code:

```
public function deleteAction($id) {
        if ($id) {
            $where[] = $this->_db->quoteInto('transazione = ?', $id);
            $this->_db->delete($this->_name, $where);   
        }
    }
```

The function is correctly called but i receive this error:

```
An error occurred

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
   $n = $this->_db->delete('tablename', "column_id = $id");
        /*or*/ 
   $q = $this->_db->quoteInto('DELETE * FROM bugs WHERE reported_by = ?', $id);
   $this->_db->query($q);
```

Comment: i've used the second option and it works... Thank's a lot